# What is the meaning of Three.js BufferGeometry vertex positions array elements order?

Tags: javascript, three.js, vertex, vertices, buffer-geometry

This is array of vertex positions taken from [this three.js documenation](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Core/BufferGeometry):

```
var vertexPositions = [
    [-1.0, -1.0,  1.0],
    [ 1.0, -1.0,  1.0],
    [ 1.0,  1.0,  1.0],

    [ 1.0,  1.0,  1.0],
    [-1.0,  1.0,  1.0],
    [-1.0, -1.0,  1.0]
];
```

If I change elements (vertices) order in this array than resulting shape is changing. I would like to know why this elements are in that specific order because I want to create shapes programmatically. To do this I just have to know why order of vertices do matter. I have tried to figure this out myself but without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're the verts defining two triangles necessary to construct a square.

E.g.:
[image]

Image taken via quick google search.  Although the diagonal runs the other direction in this case, from [-1,-1, 1] to [ 1, 1, 1].

The Z component of the 3D verts just indicating where on the Z axis the square exists.  Depending on the nature of the application, changing that value may not do anything visible.

Comment: But what about order? There is black->red->green for first triangle and green->blue->black for the second triangle. I just figured it out thanks to your image. This is counter-clockwise order.

Comment: Counter-clockwise around the surface normal.  Note: some applications use *clockwise,* but CCW is more common.